# Converting base64 into bitmap and loading into recycler view

Tags: android, base64, picasso

I'm trying to convert base64 image into bitmap image and then load it using picasso library into a recycler view. However, I get an error whenever I run my code saying I need to pass in a URI into the picasso method.

```
    public String getImage(){
      Context context =null;

        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(image, Base64.URL_SAFE);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);


        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        decodedByte.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);

      path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), decodedByte, null, null);
        return Uri.parse(path);    
}
```

DataAdapter:

```
 Picasso.with(context).load(data.get(i).getImage()).into(holder.reportImage);
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have downloaded and decoded a bitmap, there is no point of using an image loading library. All of the benefits (request queue and cache) are lost. You can simply use `holder.reportImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);`

Another approach would be to write a custom `RequestHandler`, that will decode the base64 data after downloading.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using base64 image as a placeholder for your item in recycler view I suggest you use this method to convert base64 string to bitmap -

```
 fun fromBase64ToBitmap(context: Context, base64string: String?): BitmapDrawable {
    val decodedString = Base64.decode(string, Base64.DEFAULT)
    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.size)
    return BitmapDrawable(context.resources, bitmap)
}
```

and set

```
picasso.load(your_high_quality_image)
       .placeholder(bitmapDrawableFromAboveMethod)
       .into(imageHolder)
```

Hope this helps.

Note: Code is in Kotlin but you can easily convert it in java